# How to query AWS dynamodb to get for every one hour, for every day and for 30 days?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I wrote query like below. I am able to retrieve data fromtime and totime. My problem is for every minute they are 30 records. I would like to get help to get the first record for every one hour and 24 records for one day and I need this for 30 days.

```
    var config = new QueryRequest
    {
        TableName = "dfgfdgdfg",
        KeyConditionExpression = "id= :id AND plctime BETWEEN :fromtime AND :totime",
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
               {
                ":serialNumber", new AttributeValue {S = id}
                },
               {
                ":fromtime", new AttributeValue {S = fromtime }
                },
               {
                ":totime", new AttributeValue {S = totime }
                }
            },

    };

    return await _dynamoClient.QueryAsync(config);
```

Comment: Add “ScanIndexForward: true” to your config and it will sort your results in ascending order, set to false for descending order. If you’re searching fromtime, totime, and that is a one hour period, and you are sorting ascending, just select the first result.

Comment: I want to get the data between two dates and it should select only one record for every one hour.

Comment: Ok, so to do that, in your function, before you return the results, add some logic to filter out the ones you don’t need or push the ones you do need to a new array or object, and return that array or object.

Comment: I did like that but it is taking long time to return the result. I am doing query for 30days and I am getting like for every minute 10 records, 600 records for one hour and 1440 for one day and 43200 for 30 days. each record has 250 properties. This is complex, so best is to do within the query

Answer (score 0):

In addition to storing your record as is, you could consider inserting another record that looks like this :

```
{
  pk : "DailyMarker_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd"),   // partition key
  sk : "HourlyMarker_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhh")  // range key
  record: <your entire record> 
}
```

`pk` and `sk` would be of the structure `DailyMarker_201911` and `HourlyMarker_2019112101`. Basically the part after the underscore acts as a date/time stamp with only the granularity you are interested in.

While inserting a marker record, you can add precondition checks, which, if they fail, will prevent the insertion from taking place (see [PutItem -> ConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#DDB-PutItem-request-ConditionExpression). This operation throws an exception with most SDKs if the condition evaluates to false, so you want to handle that exception.

At this point only the first record per hour is being inserted into this PK/SK combination, and all SKs for one day end up under the same PK

To query for different ranges, you will have to perform some calculations in your application code to determine the start and end buckets (pk and sk) that you want to query. While you will need to make one call per pk you are interested in, the range key can be queried using [range queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html)

You could also switch the pk to be monthly instead of daily, so that will reduce the number of PKs to query while increasing the potential for imbalanced keys (aka. hot keys)